# VBA: Find value in string

Tags: vba

I have a query that returns a column that contains directory paths to a file:

```
SELECT Sku, FileName FROM File
```

File Name can contain with of two values:

```
s:\files_checked\00132249.mtd
x:\files\checked\FileName.xml
```

I only want to process in my code the files that are found in the directory x:

In VBA what function can I use, to check if the value that comes in column FileName is:

```
x:\files\checked\
```

Thank you.

Comment: `SELECT Sku, FileName FROM File where FileName  Like 'x:\files\checked\*'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if InStr(FileName,"x:\files\checked\") >0 then
  'Process your file
end if
```

Comment: And if OP is just after the Drive path: "X:" .. as I believe he is, then use: `InStr(FileName,"x:")`  or even `IF UCASE(LEFT(FileName,2)) = "X:"